# Native equivalent of NetworkChange class; how to spot IP address changes in Windows

Tags: winapi, networking, sockets

Is there a native Windows API which does the same as the .NET System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkChange class?

Basically I'm looking for something to report changes to connectivity and IP address changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`NotifyAddrChange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366329(VS.85).aspx) from the IP Helper API should be what you're looking for.

To check if the computer is connected to a network, you might want to use [`IsNetworkAlive1`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa377522(VS.85).aspx) .

If you're developing for Windows Vista (or newer) you probably want to take a look at the [Network List Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370803(VS.85).aspx).